# Ajax pagemethod not working when i put javascript code in external Site.js file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

```
function newedito() {
    var localTime = new Date();
    var year = localTime.getFullYear();
    var month = localTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var date = localTime.getDate();
    var hours = localTime.getHours();
    var minutes = localTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = localTime.getSeconds();
    var x = document.getElementById('drdned').value;
    var y = document.getElementById('txtned1').value;
    var z = document.getElementById('txtned2').value;
    var v = "Date : " + date + "-" + month + "-" + year + " Time : " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    PageMethods.Ned(x, y, z, v, OnCallSumComplete, OnCallSumError);
    function OnCallSumComplete(result) {
        document.getElementById('updater').innerHTML = result;
    }
    function OnCallSumError() {
        document.getElementById('updater').innerHTML = "Error";
    }
}

<script src="Scripts/Site.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

when i put above written javascript in my aspx page everything works fine but when i put that function code in external Site.js file page method gets called but OnCallSumComplete() and OnCallSumError() doesn't work they are not changing the html of div('updater').
here result is a string which is either "success msg" or "exception msg".
help me please.

whole aspx file is very large to show here, this is the div in which div of id="updater" is included.

```
<div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none; border:10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .8); box-shadow: 0px 0px 200px 200px Black; position:fixed; top:10%; left:20%; right:20%; height:80%; min-width:60%; z-index: 10002;">
    <div id="control" style=" background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, .8); color:White; height:4%;">
        <div style="color:#01A9DB; float:left; font-weight:700;">OWPOST-ECLIPSE</div>
        <div style="position:static; right:0px; top:0px; float:right;">
            <a style="color:White;" href="#" onclick="togglePopUp('popUpDiv'); return false;">EXIT</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="updater" style=" background-color:White; overflow:scroll; height:96%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

this is a popup div which is shown on click of button having a form that is shown in it using ajax from server side, on click of submit button function newedito() should submit all data to pagemethod Ned() that will add data to database but when i put the js code in external file the data gets added to database but the return string is not shown by the method newedito().
i should tell you that i am having lot of forms so i prepared their html and saved them in database and i show the form 'updater' div as required and called by javascript functions.
please help.

i am including the Site.js in my master page.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>THE OPEN WEB POST</title>
        <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
        font-size:x-large;
        color: #FFFFFF;
    }
    .style2
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color:White;

    }
    .style3
    {
        color: #01A9DB;
    }
    #mynew
    {
    }
</style>
<script src="Scripts/Site.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="mynew" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div class="page" style="width: 100%; min-width:960px;">
```

i think this part of master page may help you.

Comment: Please show the html where you include the script.  As well as the error you are getting in your js console.

Comment: I am sorry I was not specific.. please show where you are including the script.

Comment: Use the network panel to see, if the script.js is loaded properly. I would suggest to register your script via ScriptReference tag in ScriptManager

Comment: what is this error
JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined
i am searching on internet but no thread is related with my issue.

Comment: i am sorry, but now on suggestion of a blog i tried to debug my asp.net website on firefox and everything is working fine there why this problem is occuring in IE

Comment: amazing! after debugging in firefox everything is working correctly. thanks all for helping me today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try registering your script via Script Manager as below. I am guessing the path to the script file is not resolved properly in your page.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="SM1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
  <Scripts>
    <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/Site.js" />
  </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: now i am getting this error on debug
The assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.60623.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' does not contain a Web resource that has the name '~/Scripts/Site.js'. Make sure that the resource name is spelled correctly.

Comment: Apologies. I have updated my answer. It should be Path and not Name.